# Android Studio - Error:Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

I'm new in the Android world.
I opened studio Android 2.2 and, after creating a new project, I get this error message:

> **Failed to sync Gradle project '...'**
>
> Error:Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'. Possible causes
>   for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache
>     may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection
>     timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync
>     project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build
>     process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve
>     this problem. Stop Gradle build processes
>     (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party
>     plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project
>     or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the
>   case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and
>   then killing all Java processes.

How can I fix the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `File`-> `Settings` -> Expand `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> Select `Build Tools` -> `Gradle` -> Under `Project Level Settings` Select `Use default gradle wrapper`. Try Gradle build again and this worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using latest version of Android studio, you can replace `distributionUrl` in  `gradle-wrapper.properties` from

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip`

to

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`.

Then sync the project and it will download necessary files and error will be fixed.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by following steps

1. download the newest version of gradle in this site: http://download.csdn.net/download/fallingwind/9604349
2. replace folder "disk-label://android-studio/gradle" with the download file(unarchive first).
3. restart AS
4. if it doesn't work, you can change the environment path of gradle.exe

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project you face a gradle sync issue. Here is the answer,

1. Just delete the .gradle file from your PC (Ex:- C:\Users\Asus\ .gradle)
2. Then create a new project
3. Now AS will restore your **gradle** files
4. Now your gradle sync problem will be fixed (This will fix all of your gradle typed sync problems and 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' error)
5. 

a).Your old project file still has this problem. But new projects will be fine. If you want to fix an old project file then all you have to do is, you can replace **distributionUrl** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbAUr.png)
in **gradle-wrapper.properties** from **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip** to **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip**.

**or**

b). If you have an old AS version, all you have to do is, Go to File-> Settings -> Expand Build, Execution, Deployment -> Select Build Tools -> Gradle -> Under Project Level Settings Select Use default gradle wrapper.Then try Gradle build. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4YW0.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was able to solve it by doing the following
in SETTINGS-GRAGLE- gradle user home I selected the root folder of the project, it began to download all the dependencies and rebuild the project, with that I was able to solve it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXjtv.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must write the path to the file with the .gradle extension in the Gradle user home: box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).