# Gradle 5.2 not supported by idea and 4.4.2 error?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

So I was getting the error in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory) post. I tried upgrading gradle and got another error relating to using an unsupported version of gradle, so I went back to the 4.4.2 version.

Now, I know this is a duplicate of the other question but the problem still exists and has not been solved for the newer versions of gradle and idea. Also **I do not want to use a wrapper**.

Error I receive:

```
Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Gradle version: 4.4.2 
IntelliJ IDEA version: 2018.3.5

You can find a test project [here](https://github.com/thechubbypanda/Gradle-Test) to reproduce the issue. Keep in mind the above versions.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How did you generate the ipr/iml files? Make sure you didn't use `gradle idea`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42518961/104891. What happens when you import `build.gradle`? Where do you see the error? What is the exact error you get with this specific `build.gradle`?

Comment: > Gradle version: 4.4.2. Where did you get this version? IDEA generates `.idea` directory, not the legacy `.ipr` files.

Comment: 4.4-2 Linux package version is not the same as 4.4.2. I've imported the project using Gradle 4.4 [without any issues](https://i.imgur.com/uffyI2Q.png).

Comment: Try using the release copy from https://gradle.org/releases/ instead. Note that there is no 4.4.2 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the official gradle install method with SDKMAN!, the problem goes away. 
The linux gradle package must be dodgy and hence IDEA is complaining.