# Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' - intellij/gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a server application using gradle as my build tool. The function is to receive UDP packets from Sensors. For this purpose I made a simple project on my windows machine using intellij. When I transferred to my Linux machine and pulled it from my repo, it had problems.

I troubleshooted a little and figured out that if I manually install gradle and specify it manually under build setting that its problem of being unable to find the wrapper was fixed.

However, a new bug was introduced after that, one that I cannot find any documentation on.

```
Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

I am not using slf4j or LoggerFactory in the entire class not have I (consciously) declared it in any configurations. Furthermore, as I said prior, I cannot find anyone with the same issue on the internet.

The program itself has not been tampered with from its working windows form and only uses imports of java.util.Arrays; java.net.DatagramPacket; java.net.DatagramSocket;

As an additional note of information, the program actually still seems to build. It is refreshing gradle that causes this error and prevent it from actually ever "running".

Comment: Can you post your gradle file here, where you define implementations? Some of the libraries may depend on slf4j.

Comment: my build.gradle is default with the only difference beiing a COMMENTED OUT line to add gson

```
dependencies {
    //compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: I was running inside the same problem today. IntelliJ was updated yesterday. For my problem the solution was mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory