# Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle

Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

When I'm cloning Android Studio project from Github, i'm having such an error. How can i fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Error:Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Comment: this is for older versions

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm with the same error

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73182006/unable-to-run-android-project-gradle-sync-failing-becuase-of-gradleconnectionex