# Unable to run android project. Gradle sync failing becuase of GradleConnectionException

Tags: android, gradle

Android studio showing error when try to build project.

```
Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

idea.log file showing this error

```
2022-07-31 14:32:43,144 [ 452438]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`
from

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

and sync your project.

Comment: well, that solved my problem. But what exactly is this fix doing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just delete the .gradle file (Ex:- C:\Users\Asus.gradle)
2. Then create a new project
3. Now AS will restore your **gradle** files
4. Now your gradle sync problem will be fixed (This will fix all of your gradle typed sync problems and 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory' error)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

i'am just delete C:\Users\Asus\ .gradle  and reopen the project, it's work for me

Answer (score 1):

To address the issue regarding the inability to load the class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory', kindly consider performing the following steps:

Please delete the following folders:

.idea
gradle
.run
build
After deleting these folders, restart the Integrated Development Environment (IDE).