# Getting this error: Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'. in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-ide

[image: A picture of Android Studio]

How do I solve this error? I have tried multiple methods but they have not worked.

I have tried most of the methods as recommended by the thread below but they have also not worked: [Android Studio - Error:Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLVED:** *Android Studio Must be uninstalled. However, all relevant files must be completely deleted from the C drive after uninstalling or the problem will remain.

The process to delete the files would be as follows:

C:Drive>Users>"Your Username">AndroidStudioProjects and all other files such  as .gradle and .android etc.*

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73182006/unable-to-run-android-project-gradle-sync-failing-becuase-of-gradleconnectionex

Comment: *"I have tried multiple methods but they have not worked."*  - Which methods?  Tell us specifically which methods you tried, and what effect each one had.  Also, have you looked in the `idea.log` file?  What does it say there?

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to SLF4J version conflict. you've make sure that all jar have the same version SLF4J please refer this 2 mins [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpscsfRGccs) to solve the same.

Comment: I tried to follow the video but when I enter java in the command prompt it returns this instead of the version:                                                                                     'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.                                                                                                                           Guessing this must mean the java file is not downloaded correctly or so then? I then tried all the different versions of gradle jdk that were on the drop down and they did not work.

Comment: I just attempted this method again after downloading java again but I have not managed to get rid of the error.

Comment: sorry,then it's above my knowledge