# Gradle Sync issues Unable to load class 'org.slf4j.LoggerFactory'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i just downloaded android studio and i got this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp7EB.png)

i searched everywhere and i found nothing , i also can't find these 3 buttons in my IDE can someone explain why please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLssA.png)

- i tried Re-downloading dependencies and sync project
- i also tried stopping Gradle build processes
- i deleted the project and made a new one and nothing has changed i always get the same result

Comment: I had the same problem, and this step helped: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663720/android-studio-errorunable-to-load-class-org-slf4j-loggerfactory)

Comment: could you add an image description, like this the post looks a bit awkward?

Answer (score 0):

Those buttons are only present for files that represent UI, i.e. @Composable function or XML views